# Busca em Largura e Busca em Profundidade

Tags: java, algoritmo-de-busca, grafo

Estou estudando para a Maratona de Programação e preciso de exemplos de busca em largura/ busca em profundidade de grafos

Comment: [Aqui](https://flyingbytes.github.io/programming/java8/functional/dfsandbfs/2017/01/02/DFS-BFS.html) tem um bom exemplo (em inglês).